# wp_dropdown_categories links 404

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

I have a custom post type which has a custom taxonomy called "Financial Sector".

I am trying to display a select box on the home page of my site so that users can select a Financial Sector and it takes you to that page.

Here is the code I am using to populate the select box.

```
<form class="fin-form-select" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/"    method="get">

<label for="choose-fin">Search by Product.</label>

<?php
$select = wp_dropdown_categories(
'taxonomy=financial-  sector
&name=financial-sector
&show_option_all=Please    Choose...
&show_count=0
&orderby=name
&order=ASC
&echo=0
');

$select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select);
echo $select;
?>

<noscript><input class="rtd-btn primary" type="submit" value="View" />  </noscript>
</form>
```

The problem I am having is that when you choose a selection, the link goes to a 404 page. I have flushed the permalinks and still no joy.

Can anybody supply me with a fix or a better way of achieving my goal.

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I was looking for. Staring me right in the face.

I have managed to fix this issue with a simple addition to the code.

```
&value_field=slug
```

So final code which works and maybe of help in the future.

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" method="get">
<label for="">Search.</label>

<?php
$select = wp_dropdown_categories(
'taxonomy=YOURTAXONOMY
&name=YOURTAXONOMY
&show_option_all=Please Choose...
&show_count=0
&orderby=name
&order=ASC
&echo=0
');

$select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return     this.form.submit()'>", $select);
echo $select;
?>

<noscript><input class="rtd-btn primary" type="submit" value="View" />    </noscript>
</form>
```

Just change YOURTAXONOMY with your custom-taxonomy slug.

Hope this helps.